# Mojo: Class "Foo::Controller::OAuth" is not a controller

Tags: perl, mojolicious

For some reason I get this message in my log,

> Class "Foo::Controller::OAuth" is not a controller

However, in my `Foo::Controller::OAuth` I have at the very top,

```
use Mojo::Base 'Mojolicious::Controller';
```

What other things can cause this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this error if the package name is wrong. For example

```
package Foo::Controller::Oauth; # notice the lower-case a in 'auth'
use Mojo::Base 'Mojolicious::Controller';
```

vs

```
package Foo::Controller::Oauth; # notice the upper-case A in 'Auth'
use Mojo::Base 'Mojolicious::Controller';
```